# PHP Udp socket close not freeing system resources

Tags: php, udp, netstat

I am using the following piece of code in a php script to process incoming data over http and forward it to another module and waits for the response. It then closes the socket.

```
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($sock,$host,$port) or die("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
if (!socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) {  
echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock));
exit;
}
$arrOpt = array('l_onoff' => 1, 'l_linger' => 1);
socket_set_block($sock);
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, $arrOpt);
$address = gethostbyname($host);

$msg = $url;
$len = strlen($msg);
socket_sendto($sock, $msg, $len, 0, $remotehost, $remoteport) ;
socket_recvfrom($sock, $buff, 1000, 0, $host, $newport);
socket_close($sock);
```

The problem faced is that the response is received correctly and the socket_close error is also returning a success(output of socket_last_error). But after that if I do a netstat I see the port being in used and the process (output of /proc/pid/status) is in sleep state.
This behavior is random in nature and I am using PHP version 5.3.8 on a Amazon EC2 cloud.

Comment: Probably just a cut/paste typo, but you're missing a `");` on the socket_bind() line.

Comment: `This behavior is random in nature` - you mean it doesn't always happen? Maybe a function of [garbage collection](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.php), try the following: 1) Try explicitly setting `$sock = NULL;` on the last line 2) Try calling [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) on the last line.

Comment: @Dave: The behavior is random means that for some of the requests received sockets are closed properly and all resources are released. But for some requests the close of socket is not complete and netstat results show those sockets to be still in use.

Comment: Any luck with the GC suggestion above?

Comment: No change after setting $sock = NULL and calling gc_collect_cycles, it returns zero value. Is there any way to know if all the system resources are getting freed after call to socket_close()?

Answer (score 0):

its about **TIME_WAIT**  ... to free the socket

in  Linux run  `# /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout` to find out .... (default 60 sec)

[more about](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-command-forcibly-close-socket-ports-in-time_wait-state/)